# UNet : NetworkManager.spawnPrefabs Returns a null List

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm still new to unity so please forgive me if i just wasted your time .But i appreciate if you help me in this problem :

I'm creating a multiplayer game using unity And I want to get the list of Registered spawnablable Prefabs SO i searched the Scipting API and i found this method :[NetworkManager.spawnPreabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager-spawnPrefabs.html)

Here is my script :

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 using UnityEngine.Networking;

 public class CardSpawner : NetworkBehaviour
 {




public override void OnStartServer(){
    distributeCards ();
    Debug.Log ("THE METHOD WORKED!!!!");
} 

IEnumerator Mycoroutine (bool cardDistribution){
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(10f);
    if (ClientScene.ready) {

        RpcdistributeCards (true);


    }
}

[Server]
public bool distributeCards(){
    bool cardDistribution = false;
    //int playersNumber;

    //NetworkManager netM = new NetworkManager ();
    //netM = GetComponent<NetworkManager> ();
    //playersNumber = netM.numPlayers; 


        cardDistribution = true;

    StartCoroutine ("Mycoroutine",cardDistribution);



    return cardDistribution;
}

[ClientRpc]
public void RpcdistributeCards (bool Permission){

    Debug.Log ("The Client RPC Worked ");
    Transform startPositionTransform;
    Vector2 position, finalPosition;
    NetworkManager NetM;

    List<Transform> startPositionsList;

    Vector2 Increment = new Vector2 (1.41f, 0f);
    NetM = GetComponent<NetworkManager> ();
    List<GameObject> Cards;

    Cards = NetM.spawnPrefabs;
    if (Permission) {
        Debug.Log ("The If statement worked ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {

                GameObject CurrentGameObject = Cards [Random.Range (0, Cards.Count)];

                Cards.Remove (CurrentGameObject);
                Debug.Log (CurrentGameObject);
                startPositionsList = NetM.startPositions;

                switch (i) {
                case 1:
                    startPositionTransform = startPositionsList [0];
                    position = startPositionTransform.position;
                    finalPosition = position + Increment;
                    var cardFirstPosition = (GameObject)Instantiate (CurrentGameObject, finalPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    startPositionTransform = startPositionsList [1];
                    position = startPositionTransform.position;
                    finalPosition = position + Increment;
                    var cardSecondPosition = (GameObject)Instantiate (CurrentGameObject, finalPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    startPositionTransform = startPositionsList [2];
                    position = startPositionTransform.position;
                    finalPosition = position + Increment;
                    var cardThirdPosition = (GameObject)Instantiate (CurrentGameObject, finalPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    startPositionTransform = startPositionsList [3];
                    position = startPositionTransform.position;
                    finalPosition = position + Increment;
                    var cardFourthPosition = (GameObject)Instantiate (CurrentGameObject, finalPosition, Quaternion.identity);
                    break;
                }


            }
        }

    }
}
}
```

before runing the console shows no problem but when runing the game the console shows this error :

```
  NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
   object
   CardSpawner.RpcdistributeCards (Boolean Permission) (at 
   Assets/Scripts/CardSpawner.cs:59)
```

Which is this line of code :

```
 Cards = NetM.spawnPrefabs;
```

I don't understand why it returns null . 
I appreciate any help . thanks for reading .

Comment: it's not `spawnPrefabs` that returns `null`, your `NetM` is `null` - are you sure you have a `NetworkManager` component on the same object your script is attached to? On a second thought, `GetComponent<NetworkManager> ();` should probably be [`NetworkManager.singleton`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManager-singleton.html)

Comment: It worked !!! Thanks for your answer  @UnholySheep ,Idid like you said .Now after i thought about it it 's more than logical . how can i get a component that doesn't exist on the player prefab !!! .thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't be sorry to ask for help!

```
List<GameObject> Cards;

Cards = NetM.spawnPrefabs;
```

Try making NetM & Cards list public

```
public NetworkManager NetM;
public List<GameObject> Cards;
```

This will show the List in the inspector so you can assign the variables

NullReferenceException occurs when something is not assigned that is being accessed by a script.
So make those variables and classes public and assign them inside inspector

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an 
object
```

Comment: I can't make them public that will throw an error 'parse error " maybe beacuse it's a client RPC but see the answer of @UnholySheep it solved the problem . thanks for answer .